# Output coming unreasonably large in C for the equation x+ y^2 + z^3

Tags: c

```
//Experiment 3 Task 4 b.)
#include<stdio.h>
void main(){
    int x,y,z,ans;
    printf("\nEnter the value of x.   ");
    scanf("%i",&x);
    printf("\nEnter the value of y.   ");
    scanf("%i",&y);
    printf("\nEnter the value of z.   ");
    scanf("%i",&z);
    ans = (x + (y^2) + (z^3));
    printf("\nAnswer = %i",&ans);
}
```

OUTPUT:
Enter the value of x.   1

Enter the value of y.   2

Enter the value of z.   4

Answer = -483189484

Comment: `^` is a bitwise XOR operator. I doubt that's what you meant to use

Comment: Don't assume that C works the way you want it to. Rather learn how it actually works. `^` is bitwise XOR, not power of.

Comment: `y^2` -> `y*y` and `z^3` -> `z*z*z` You could use the function `pow` but since you are dealing with integers (and the power is low) simply write the expression

Comment: So in this case just do `y*y` and `z*z*z`. You can also use the `pow` function from math.h, but that one assumes floating point. The language is a bit broken here, there's actually no fixed point pow function.

Comment: Note that when `z > 1290` you will get integer overflow from `z³`.

Comment: `^` is not power operator. Printf prints reference and it is UB. Generally, you need to start form the C book. There is no other way. SO in not a tutorial or teaching portal.

Answer (score 3):

There are two issues with your code:

1. With regards to large value, you are printing address rather than actual answer. So remove the `&` when you print
2. The `^` operator in C represents the bitwise XOR. So you can either use the `pow` function, (dont forget to put `#include <math.h>`) or write your own version of it to get correct results.

Comment: rootkonda and [@4386427](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65899025/output-coming-unreasonably-large-in-c-for-the-equation-x-y2-z3#comment116514335_65899025) I would not recommend using a  floating point function like `pow()` for an integer problem.  Various edge case issues once FP math involved as well as to/from conversion issues.

Comment: Tip: "or write your own version": Searching for `ipow()` reports many alternatives - _some_ are good.